# Problem with adding a texture from image

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to add a texture of solar cell to a .STL solar panel drawing and then export as OBJ+MTL. 
I've did the following:
1. Imported an STL file, added material and then texture via adding a PNG image (see printscreen below). 
2. Used "Smart UV Project", with default values via the UV's menu in Shading/UVs.
3. Exported as OBJ.

I have two problems with the result:
a. The projection is uneven, unregular, either in Material or in Texture view (see below)
b. While the Material view features small pattern (I've used Mapping size for that), the Texture has a large projection of the pattern.

I guess I'm doing a number of mistakes with the proper projection settings, but having trouble to find the proper way. 
Thanks in advance!

[image: STL Wireframe]

[image: Material View]
[image: Texture View after re-opening as OBJ]

[image: Menu view]

Comment: I would definitely suggest to **use "Project from view" mapping** in this case (from the top view, e.g. press Numpad 7, then UV-mapping method "project from view") To change the visible size of the texture you can **scale the UV-map in the UV-mapping window** (by selecting all with "A" and using "S" to scale)